# jQuery ContextMenu DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I am using this contextMenu template: http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html

and i would like to change the place where the menu appears, i mean i want it to ALWAYS Appear from the point i click to the bottom cause sometimes the lists contains lots of items and when its appears from the point clicked to upward Most of the list Disappear. i tried looking at the documentation and i came across the `$.ui.position` but i dont know if thats it and actually i didnt understand it.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Below you said you solved it but did not answer the question here. Can you please post your solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').contextMenu('menu',{
    onShowMenu: function(e, menu) {
        e.pageX=100;
        e.pageY=400;
        return menu;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: well for my case it didnt exactly work but it gave me a hint on solving the problem :) thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

**determinePosition** - provided in documentation of the plugin.

Determine the position of the menu in respect to the given trigger object.

determinePosition: function(opt.$menu)

Ex:

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: 'span.context-menu',
    determinePosition: function($menu){
        // Position using jQuery.ui.position 
        // http://api.jqueryui.com/position/
        $menu.css('display', 'block')
            .position({ my: "center top", at: "center bottom", of: this, offset: "0 5"})
            .css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Worked for me!! I know this is a 9 year old question, and I hope the next person viewing it will not spend an hour fixing it.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry Im new here and I'm still learning to present the answers better.. Thanks for the input. I've Edited the answer with an explanation.