# JQuery ContextMenu forcing dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the JQuery ContextMenu: http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html 
i am facing the position problem thing, i search the forum and i couldnt find what i need so here it is:

Sometimes my Menu gets filled with large amount of data so sometimes it opens upwards and most of the list disappears.

I tried this solution:[jQuery ContextMenu DropDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998244/jquery-contextmenu-dropdown) and it didnt work for me as i also tried to work around the answer and still no use.

i want to force it to open downwards starting of my click's position.

Here is the code:

```
$.contextMenu({
                selector: '#vis',
                trigger: 'left',
                build: function($trigger, e) {
                     var options = { 
                        callback: function(key, options) {
                            var m = "clicked: " + key;
                            //window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
                            if(key!="quit")
                            {
                                SearchAddTweets(d,key);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#vis').contextMenu(false);
                            }
                        },
                        items: {disabled: false}
                    };
                    options.items["Date"] = {
                        name: d
                    };
                    options.items.sep1 = "---------";
                    $.each(BigWordsDates[d], function(k, v) {
                        for(var prop = 0; prop < OriginalTweets.length; prop++)
                        {
                            if(OriginalTweets[prop][0]!=null)
                            { 
                                if(OriginalTweets[prop][1].search(d)>=0 && OriginalTweets[prop][0].search(k)>=0)
                                {
                                     options.items[k] = {
                                        name: "Trend: "+k+", Freq:"+v
                                    };                                
                                }
                            }                            
                        }

                    });

                    options.items.sep1 = "---------";
                    options.items.quit = {
                        name: "Quit"
                    };

                    if(t>=100)
                    {
                         e.pageX=e.pageX;
                         e.pageY += 100;
                    }


                    return options;
                }
            });
```

Comment: numerous contextmenu plugins... should define which one with docs link